# How do I make cURL requests using Haxe that is compiled to PHP?

Tags: php, curl, haxe

I can't find anything regarding cURL on the Haxe API for PHP and I'm a bit lost. Can someone help me out?

`sys.Http` uses sockets on the compiled PHP which isn't my desired outcome.

Comment: You’ll probably have to use native escapes like https://api.haxe.org/php/Syntax.html#code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since haxe doesn't have all the php extensions built in you will likely have to use the [Syntax features](https://api.haxe.org/php/Syntax.html).

There's a lot of options on that page but the 'code' function is pretty versatile and dangerous:

```
Syntax.code("$tuCurl = curl_init();");
```

Anyway, you should be able to use curl using some of those features!